# F#: Can someone explain my compiler error?

Tags: f#

Anyone know what the problem with this code is?

```
let rec Foo(a,b) =
    match a () with
    | None -> Some(b)
    | Some(c) -> Some(Foo(c,b))
```

Here's the compiler error:

"Type mismatch. Expecting a     'a     but given a     'a option     The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''a option'"

Comment: Just for funsies, what *exactly* are you trying to do? Maybe someone can suggest a better way to write your function.

Comment: @Juliet - I didn't feel comfy going into a better way to write the function without knowing, but, until you mentioned it I didn't think about the fact that I stopped because of the lack of understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's try to reproduce how the compiler tries to infer types here.

```
let rec Foo(a,b) =
    match a () with
    | None -> Some(b)
    | Some(c) -> Some(Foo(c,b))
```

"Ok, so I see `a ()`. `a` must be a function from `unit` to some type, I don't know which one yet. I'll call it `'a`."

```
a : unit -> 'a
```

"The result of `a ()` is matched with `None`/`Some` patterns. So `'a` must be a `'b option` and `c` has the type `'b`." (Again, `'b` stands for an unknown, as of yet, type).

```
a : unit -> 'b option
с : 'b
```

"No functions or methods are called on `b` (except `Some`, which doesn't narrow the type down, and `Foo`, the type of which we don't know so far). I'll denote its type by `'c`."

```
a : unit -> 'b option
b : 'c
c : 'b
```

"`Foo` returns `Some(b)` in one of the branches, so the return type must be `'c option`."

```
Foo : (unit -> 'b option) * 'c -> 'c option
```

"Am I done yet? No, I need to check that all types in the expression make sense. Let's see, in the `Some(c)` case, `Some(Foo(c,b))` is returned. So `Foo(c,b) : 'c`. Since `Foo` returns an `option`, I know `'c` must be `'d option` for some `'d`, and `b : 'd`. Wait, I already have `b : 'c`, that is, `b : 'd option`. `'d` and `'d option` have to be the same type, but this is impossible! There must be an error in the definition. I need to report it." So it does.

Comment: Very nice breakdown.  So in other words, the compiler is torn between 'a and 'a option option option option ... option option etc.

Answer (score 4):

It always helps to break things down step-by-step. As written, Foo has the type:

```
val Foo : (unit -> 'a option) * 'b -> 'b option
```

Each expression in an active pattern must evaluate to the same type. The first pattern match in your expression has the type:

```
'b option
```

Therefore, the other pattern must also evaluate to `'b option` or `'a option`. The way that you have it here, it is returning `'a option option`.

This is a peculiar function but you could correct the compiler error by returning any option value in the second pattern match. Here is the only example that I can think of that looks anything like the above:

```
let Foo2(a,b) =
    match a () with
    | None -> Some(b)
    | c    -> c
```

HTH.

Comment: _As written_, `Foo` doesn't have this type, and in fact doesn't have any other type; that's the point of the error!

Comment: I understand your point but I copied that signature right from the F# interpreter in Visual Studio. Yes, the code won't compile or run as shown but F# does make a pretty good effort at it. =)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `a()` as an option which is the first parameter in `Foo`, but, in the last line `c` is a type, and yet you pass it into the recursive call.

That is what is leading to the error.

You will want to either have `c` be an option type.